# Path for Paperclip missing.png

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, image, amazon-s3, paperclip

using paperclip's default/standard configuration, a model without an image will result in having a path `http://localhost:3000/avatars/thumb/missing.png`

I am using paperclip with S3, and I would like to use a `missing.png` from my storage.

Is there a way to set the path for the missing.png via s3?

I am aware of the `:default_url` but it doesnt seem to work with the s3 information that other images use

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`'default_url'` is the  url to use when an image is `nil`.

One other scenario would be that url for your attachment exists but it just doesn't exists at the location or s3, in that case the **Frontend** tries to find the file but returns the **error** as unable to find the file.

So the solution here could be you replace all your missing url file with some asset file via javascript like this : [jQuery/JavaScript to replace broken images](https://stackoverflow.com/q/92720/985051)